# What is the proper way to update a @Published variable from the network layer?

Tags: swift, swiftui

Let's say I have a managed state object like this

```
class SomethingService: ObservableObject {

   //views are listening to this
   @Published var statusString: String = ""

   func doNetwork() async {
      //how to pass statusString to a network class so that it can continually update this string every step along the way
      try await NetworkManager.doNetwork(somehow:statusString)           
    }    
}
```

Comment: Are you asking for `statusString` to update once the `doNetwork` call is completed? Additionally, it looks like you posted part of your question in the code's comments. Please add that to the body of your question.

Comment: statusString needs to be updated say every 10% of download

Comment: How about [`@MainActor`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/mainactor) or [`DispatchQueue.main.async`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchqueue/1781006-main)?

Comment: You need support for this in your NetworkManager but if you do then I assume you could publish the value using Combine, and then subscribe to it in your service type and there update your status string.

Comment: Would something like this work for you: https://gist.github.com/Baglan/24e0090c1b56b4f0155cc5284f46cd62

Comment: It sounds like doNetwork should be an async stream

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this?

```
class SomethingService: ObservableObject {

   //views are listening to this
   @Published var statusString: String = ""

   func doNetwork() async {
      for await status in NetworkManager.doNetwork() {
          Task { @MainActor in
              self.statusString = status
          }
      }        
   }    
}
```